# redirect for www.xyz.com/?/12345 to domain.com/12345.html

Tags: .htaccess

we have to move one of our web projects but have (printed) urls/QR Codes in the market, that currently would fail.

Example:
QR Code resolves to 
http://www.domain1.com/?/12345

We would like to forward this url to our new server with the help of .htaccess on domain1.com - the forward should go to:
https://www.domain2.com/?/12345

We cannot just forward ALL requests, as ONLY the /?/xxxx content has been moved ...

We know the /?/ has not been the best choice, but those codes cannot be modified right now any more :(

Answer (score 0):

You must first check the query string for the appropriate pattern, and if the request is for the root. Then redirect to the new domain

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/\d+$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domain2.com/?%{QUERY_STRING} [R,L]
```

To check for a slash, followed by anything is the same as checking for just a slash, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/
```

---

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)). *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: unfortunately, there is NO possibility to check against the query string. 
Only "common" is the /?/  between the domain-name and the variable.

Is there a way to check for /?/ ?

Comment: The first slash is part of the request path, the second slash is part of the query string.